# R Shiny toggle text of actionLink

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do something which I thought would be relatively simple, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I am attempting to have an actionLink which, when pressed, provides additional information for the user. When pressed again it hides the information. I can do this fine, but what I am struggling with is updating the text of the actionLink.

I want it to read "Show additional" when the extra information is hidden, and then "Hide additional" when the information is exposed. I have read the following questions/answers, but cannot quite get it to work.

[Modify shiny action button once it is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590653/modify-shiny-action-button-once-it-is-clicked)

[Update label of actionButton in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33777991/update-label-of-actionbutton-in-shiny)

I have provided a simple code for this below, though the real example will be a lot more complex.

Thank you for your time and help.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(useShinyjs(),
                         actionLink("button", "Show additional"),
                         hidden(
                           div(id='text_div',
                               verbatimTextOutput("text")
                               )
                           )
                         )
               ),

  server = function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      toggle('text_div')
      output$text <- renderText({"Additional"})
    })

  }
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for the value of `input$button`(which increments by 1 each time you click on it) and update the `actionLink` `label` parameter in function of its value with `updateActionButton` :

```
shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(useShinyjs(),
              actionLink("button", "Show additional"),
              hidden(div(id='text_div', verbatimTextOutput("text")))
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      toggle('text_div')
      output$text <- renderText({"Additional"})

      if (input$button %% 2 == 1) {
        txt <- "Hide Additional"
      } else {
        txt <- "Show Additional"
      }
      updateActionButton(session, "button", label = txt)
    })

  }
)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I was almost there, but just was missing the correct formatting of the modulo operator. Appreciate your time and help.